# Qt connecting a slider to a doublespinbox

Tags: c++, qt, slider, qspinbox

this is the code I am using to convert the int of my slider into a double.

```
void simMotionControl::on_horizontalSlider_speed_valueChanged(int value)
{
    value = double (value/100); //i set the range of the slider from 0 to 10000
    ui->doubleSpinBox_speed->setValue(value);
}
```

When I connect my slider to my double spin box, it only changes its number for every integer how can i have my slider change my double spin box to the precision of two decimal places? also, i want to also connect the spin box back to my slider so if i change the value in the spinbox the slider will change. thank you!!

Comment: Start by setting the value with a `double` not an `int` ? Unless this is not your actual code ?

Comment: the slider only takes and outputs int values so i needed to convert that into a double. this is the actual code

Comment: I am not shure, but there is a property at HorizontalSlider - step. By default step is equal to 1. I don't know is there any way to make it like 0.1 or smth else, but you can try discover that opportunity. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing two integers which always results in an integer value. You should divide `value` by `100.0` which is decimal :

```
void simMotionControl::on_horizontalSlider_speed_valueChanged(int value)
{
    double val = value/100.0; //i set the range of the slider from 0 to 10000
    ui->doubleSpinBox_speed->setValue(val);
}
```

It is also possible to cast value to double prior to the division :

```
double val = (double)value/100;
```

For updating the value of the slider when changing spinbox you can have :

```
void simMotionControl::on_doubleSpinBox_speed_valueChanged(double arg1)
{
    ui->horizontalSlider_speed->setValue(arg1*100);
}
```

Comment: Only a side note... you could use more modern template-style cast: value = static_cast<double>(value)/100;

Comment: i tried all the ways you mentioned to convert the int value into a double value but has not worked... i still only get integers on my doublespinbox thanks again!

Comment: @fluxD613 You should assign it to a double variable. I edited the answer.

Comment: when i try to control the slider from the double spin box, it reverts everything back to integers only here is my code: `void simMotionControl::on_horizontalSlider_speed_valueChanged(int speedslider_val)
//must change slider value to double bacause slider only does integers
{
    double speed_actual = (double) speedslider_val/100.0;
    ui->doubleSpinBox_speed->setValue(speed_actual);
}

void simMotionControl::on_doubleSpinBox_speed_valueChanged(double speed_actual)
{
    int speedslider_val = (int) speed_actual*100;
    ui->horizontalSlider_speed->setValue(speedslider_val);
}
`

Comment: It should be : `int speedslider_val = speed_actual*100; ui->horizontalSlider_speed->setValue(speedslider_val);`. You should omit casting to int. Because you would miss decimal point values.